# Question about safety of eating cooked bread if it is over or under-proofed

Tags: baking, food-safety, bread

Not sure if my dough was over or under proofed. I cooked it and it is quite dense. It did not rise as much as I thought it would. I cooked for the time in recipe, and then a little longer. Can we still eat it? It is rye bread. I know I cannot eat the raw dough, but just wanted to make sure we can eat the cooked loaf.

Answer (score 6):

Under- or over-proofed bread will change the "crumb" of the bread but has nothing to do with food safety. If it is baked fully it will be safe even if it's a little dense or too airy.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to tell if a loaf is fully baked is to measure the internal temperature.  You are looking for 190 - 200F (88 - 93C).  The higher end is for dough with egg and or milk.  That said, a dense final product is likely to be caused by other factors (yeast or starter inactivity, lack of gluten development, proofing errors).  A well made loaf that is under-cooked will still rise.  I doubt your final loaf is a safety concern.  If you like the flavor, make use of it. You can always slice and toast.